# WPF MouseMove event of listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mousemove

In my wpf application, i am facing problem to get item from listview when mouse is moved over different items in mousemove event.
    Say for example if listview contains item listed as ,

```
    "one"
    "two"
    "three"
    ----

Then in mousemove event if my mouse moved over the item two then i have to get "two" in my code.

Please help me as i am very new to this WPF.
Regards
Ravi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a very simplistic solution, but it does seem to do what you want it to do.

```
    private void listView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = Mouse.DirectlyOver;

        if (item != null && item is TextBlock)
            Debug.Print((item as TextBlock).Text);
    }
```

I hope this helps.